# civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages table huge

Tags: database, civimobile

We installed Civimobile as a test, and aren't yet using it. It does look great!

We have noticed a file on our server of gigantic proportions: 
civicrm/civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages.ibd: 18GB

Is this just generated by the Civimobile API? And if so, have we done something wrong in our setup that it has become so large? I think the extension was enabled for about 4 weeks, and has been disabled for about 6 weeks. And we haven't been using the CiviMobile app at all when the extension was enabled.

How can we reduce the size of this file, or remove it? We don't want to use up that much space on our server if we don't have to.

Thanks for your help.

Civicrm 5.24, Drupal 7.69

Comment: You might want to open an Issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi/-/issues as the devs are more likely to be watching that

Answer (score 1):

seamuslee wrote 11 months ago on https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi/-/issues/57 :
One thing I have found is editing the scheduled job Civimobile clean old push notification messages and setting a command / API parameter

count_of_day=1

which means keep only 1 days worth of notification messages can help.

Works :)

Answer (score 0):

We are having this same issue. The civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages table has grown to 4GB with 14million records in just 14 days. There is a 'Civimobile clean old push notification messages' scheduled job but it only cleans notifications older than 90 days.

This appears to be causing timeouts on our server due to low resources. Is there any way we can turn this excessive logging off?